# Different Vim highlighting groups for user-defined function and built-in function

Tags: vim, editor, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting

right now, in Vim, in python3, if I do:

```
def myFunc():
    print("Hello World")
```

'print' and 'myFunc' both appear purple because in my vim colorscheme I have:

`hi Function guifg=#8059A8 guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=54 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold`

how do I set different highlight colors for user-defined and built-in functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can link the `pythonBuiltin` syntax group to any highlight group you like using:

```
hi link pythonBuiltin Error
```

Of course that's just an example, you probably want to define your custom highlight group and use it instead of `Error`.

Please note that this includes all Python builtins (including `True`, `False`, or `None`), not just the ones that look like functions (like `print()`, `list()` or `dict()`)